# Google oauth error

Tags: android

I tried to link my app with gplus it works fine in separate and not when I merged it with my project app. Please take a look at the below gradle file and help me if u can.

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.1.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

*It shows the following error when i try to run:*

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$zze com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$zza.zza(android.content.Context, android.os.Looper, com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf, java.lang.Object, com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks, com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$OnConnectionFailedListener)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, 
I tried with changing 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2' and  'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2' to

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.0'
'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
```

Try to change the version.

Comment: Hi yeah i tried by changing.. nw am getting another error. I cannot login into my acct.. login fails when i try to login with the error:                
Caused by: bafl: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Application credential header not valid. Please fix the client to pass a valid application credential header.

Comment: Thank you archana.. i got it solved by adding updating and adding google json file with the project which i forgot to do...

Comment: Ok. What was the issue? Is this is because of JSON file or the version?

Comment: @DummyAccountA Ok, Please accept the answer, If the issue is solved. So it could help others. :-)